# sql report 3.0 deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

Encountered deadlock when I need to query two different sales report on the same table.

query on both report is

```
select * from tableA
inner join tableB on ...
inner join tableC on ...
```

My solution for both sales report

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
select * from tableA
inner join tableB on ...
inner join tableC on ...
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

is this the correct solution?.

I think the sales reports will not be accurate as there will be dirty read

Answer (score 0):

Normally you won't get a deadlock just by using two `SELECTS` on the same tables. Do you have some processes writing to it? Is this the whole report code?
Do you use production table or replicated copies of them for the report? This all may count into it.

I would suggest you run the SQL Profiler (Server Side Trace) to run a trace and examine the result. You normally should find the deadlock graph, which means you can exactly determine which query runs before and conflicted with another query.

As a workaround for this, you can use your solution, but just as an workaround. You may have a to high inaccuracy.